# Using UNIQUE (col1, col2) or using a composite primary key for a relation table in SQLite/SQL?

Tags: database, database-design, sql, relational-database, sqlite

i’m working on a project where i’m using SQLite and where i have a few relation tables looking similar to this one:

```
CREATE TABLE tag_entry_relation
(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
tag_id INTEGER REFERENCES tag(id),
entry_id INTEGER REFERENCES entry(id)
);
```

**I know that the two “referencing” columns will together be unique (so there will be no duplicates).**

***I’m considering whether to use the UNIQUE constraint or if it’s better to use a composite primary key***

The reason i see for using a composite primary key is simply that it requires one column less than the other option

I don't see a reason for using a UNIQUE constraint except that i'm more used to this than using a composite primary key, so i'm worried i might be missing something

What would you recommend? Grateful for help!

PS: As far as i can tell there’s no difference between SQL and SQLite in regards to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know two reasons for using an `id` column in that situation:

- if you have a strict convention to give every table in your database a single primary key named `id`
- if you cannot exclude the possibility `tag_entry_relation` might becoming referenced by another table int the future (which would lead to ugly combined two-column foreign key references)

If none of those two reasons applies, then go ahead with the composite primary key, else introduce the `id` column.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use composite primary key as it will be combined together so that the combination is unique. It will allow you to set multiple unique columns as a constraint.